# How to highlight multiple words using different formatters in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I need to perform highlighting for multiple words into the same field but for each one using a specific formatter (prefix and postfix).

Let's say that I have the `description` field and for a document it has the value: `Einstein always excelled at math and physics from a young age`. How to highlight `math` with a pair of a specific prefix and postfix AND ALSO `physics`with a different prefix-postfix pair? So, in the end I would like to obtain:

`Einstein always excelled at <em class="hl-red">math</em> and <em class="hl-green">physics</em> from a young age`

The reason is that in the frontend I have different CSS classes with `background-color: red;` for `hl-red` and `background-color: green` for `hl-green` for example.

However, I was managed to highlight multiple words into the same field but with the same prefix-postfix pair all over the places, which is not what I want actually. In addition, I tried to add multiple HtmlFormatter entries in solrconfig.xml:

`<highlighting>
    ..............
    <formatter name="html" default="true" class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="hl-red">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em class="hl-red">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="hl-green">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em class="hl-green">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
    </formatter>
    ..............
 </highlighting>`

but I got `HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr: Unknown formatter: hl-green`. Also, I didn't find a way to specify an array of prefixes in Solr Admin UI nor in spring-data-solr, just a simple query like this:

`SimpleHighlightQuery query = new SimpleHighlightQuery(Objects.requireNonNull(criteria));
    HighlightOptions highlightOptions = new HighlightOptions()
        .addFields(fields)
        .setSimplePrefix(prefix)
        .setSimplePostfix(postfix);
    query.setHighlightOptions(highlightOptions);
    query.setPageRequest(pageable);
    return solrTemplate.queryForHighlightPage(MY_CORE, query, MyModel.class);`

My assumption is that it is a limitation of the Solr itself.

I was thinking about to write a custom fragmentsBuilder but I do not know exactly if it is the case nor how to do that. For another workaround I was thinking to execute for each word a highlight query, then to store the result, then to execute for the second word another highlight query, store the result and so on. But I don't think it is a good and elegant solution because I will have problems when executing the second query if the second word is: "em" or "class" or "red"/"green" (nested undesired highlighting will occur).

I am using spring-data-solr into a Spring Boot application and Solr 6.6.5 as a (http) service.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Please give me an advice! Any idea will be much appreciated!